# Why isn't my hasura query using an index scan?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, graphql, query-optimization, hasura

I'm following the guide from Hasura on how to optimize my queries found at:

https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/queries/performance.html#data-validation-pg-indexes

but my queries still are executing sequential scans instead of index scans and I don't understand why.

I'm using non-nullable scalar variables and I've created indexes but the problem persists.

Index:

`CREATE INDEX shop_index ON "shop" (shop_origin);`

Query:

```
query get_storefront_data ($shop_origin: String!) {
      shop_by_pk(shop_origin: $shop_origin) {
        app_subscription_type
        currency_code
        usage_count
      }      
    }
```

Variables:

```
{
  "shop_origin": "test.myshopify.com"
}
```

Execution plan (generated by the "Analyze" button in the Hasura console):

```
Aggregate  (cost=1.05..1.07 rows=1 width=32)
  ->  Seq Scan on shop  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=1 width=16)
        Filter: (shop_origin = 'test.myshopify.com'::text)
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the query execute Index scans instead of Sequential scans?

Comment: If the table is small the database engine itself will ignore the index. Of note, this is a database engine problem and has nothing to do with Hasura. Edit: This isn't totally true, Postgres can decide if it's more efficient to not use an index and it can happen with both large and small tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For tiny tables, a sequential scan is the most efficient access method. Use realistic amounts of data to perform a meaningful performance test.